# Character to be escaped is missing

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I pulled my android code from the repository freshly into my new laptop. Everything is looking good, but when I run the code I'm getting this Exception.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> character to be escaped is missing
```

Please let me know how to resolve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to find the stack trace for the error and go from there. Look in the Gradle console and/or the Messages window (View -> Tool Windows).

Comment: try this.... Try to upgrade your buildToolsVersion to "23.0.3",like this:

compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

Comment: Somewhere in your source code there is a backslash (\) character that cannot be interpreted as escaped character. The next character is not meaningful as escape character. Most likely you have a string where you added a backslash but it is not escaped, it supposed to be double backslashes (\\). I would check strings which are containing file paths, that is a common mistake.

Comment: I was doing this: `pathName.replaceAll(Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\\\"), File.separator)` instead of this: `pathName.replaceAll("\\\\",Matcher.quoteReplacement(File.separator))`. Oops. Get the same `character to be escaped is missing` error.